mybatis-dynamic-sql, when using groupBy, where{} OR having{} will be wrong
Here is the one i'm using: https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-dynamic-sql/tree/master
I've been stuck here for quite a while and don't know why. When using groupBy and ‘where OR having’ has a filter，there will be some error as below. And only pure groupBy without 'where or having' filter ， it will be ok. But you know fitlers are quite necessary. So anybody helps me.
SQL in the first photo works in navicat, and the next dynamic SQL is absoulutely the same, but error.



Only comment the code in {}, otherwise will be wrong.
Wish can query data with 'where & having' filters.

Solved.
The import of 'select' is wrong.
import org.mybatis.dynamic.sql.util.kotlin.mybatis3.select
import org.mybatis.dynamic.sql.util.kotlin.spring.select
And thanks for the amazing project again.  https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-dynamic-sql
